# The best (or worst?) counterexample to Schwarz theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative, examples-counterexamples

The well known theorem of Schwarz asserts the following: suppose that $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^k$ function and pick some sequence $(j_1,...,j_k)$ of length $k$ where each $j_i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$. Then all mixed partial derivatives of $k$-th order over variables $x_{j_i}, i=1,2,...,k$ coincide, no matter in which order we diffrentiate. 
I would like to see the following example: function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which has all partial derivatives up to $k$-th order (where $k$ is a fixed positive integer) but for *every* point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ all $k$-th order derivatives has different values. In other words I would like to see an example where for every permutation of variables we get different value of partial derivative and this happens not only in *one* but in *every* point.

Comment: I don't think such an example will be possible. If the partial derivatives do not commute at some point then the partial derivatives of $f$ cannot all be continuous at that point, but there are restrictions on the points of discontinuity of a differentiable function. [The answer to this question describes what the points of discontinuity can look like for one dimension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be) For your question you are looking for higher derivatives in higher dimension, it may be that these restrictions remain in this setting.