# Can a one-sided limit exist at a discontinuity point of a derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and fix $a \in \mathbb{R}.$ By L'Hôpital's rule, since
$$ \frac{(f(x)-f(a))'}{(x-a)'} = f'(x),$$
if either limit
$$ \lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x), \qquad \lim_{x \to a^-} f'(x)$$
exists, then it equals $f'(a).$ Hence, if both of them exist, $f'(x) \to f'(a)$ as $x \to a$ and $f'$ is continuous at $a.$ Equivalently, if $f'$ is not continuous at $a,$ then at least one of the one-sided limits does not exist. This is enough to show that every discontinuity of $f'$ is essential, but I'd like to know whether it can be assured that **neither** one-sided limit exists.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How about $f(x)=0$ for $x\le0$, $ f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $ x>0$?

Comment: @David, in view of the wrong answer perhaps you should post yours.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks a lot. I see one of the one-sided limits might exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Define $f$ by $f(x)=0$ for $ x\le0$ and $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x>0$. One can show $f$ is differentiable and that $f'$ is not continuous at 0. Obviously, the left-hand limit of $f'$ at 0 exists.