# Is there any function that has a derivative almost everywhere, but where the derivative function is everywhere discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076701/is-there-a-function-whose-derivative-is-discontinuous-everywhere) asks whether there exists a function that has a derivative that is discontinuous everywhere. Is there any function that has a derivative almost everywhere, but where the derivative function is everywhere discontinuous, for the definition of continuity that takes into account only the inputs where the derivative is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a bounded measurable function on $[0,1]$ that has no continuity point even ae in the sense that for every $x \in [0,1]$ there is no $g$ continuous at $x$ st $g=f$ ae on a small interval near $x$.

To construct such, one finds $E$ measurable st for for every subinterval $I \subset [0,1]$ both $I \cap E, I \cap E^c$ have non zero measure and take $f=\chi_E$.

Then $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is differentiable ae and $F'=f$ ae so $F'$ restricted to its set of differentiability points is definitely not continuous at any differentiability point since for any $x$ where $F'$ exist and any interval $I$ containing $x$, we have $F'=1$ on a set of positive measure in $I$ and $F'=0$ also on a set of positive measure in $I$, so $\liminf_{y \to x, F' \text {exists at y}}F'(y)=0$ and $\limsup_{y \to x, F' \text {exists at y}}F'(y)=1$