# Functions which are continuous but the left-hand and right-hand derivatives do not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, graphing-functions, visualization

I'll state my question up-front, and then provide some motivation afterwards. Is there an example of a function that is

- Defined in a neighbourhood of a point $a$,
- Continuous at $a$,
- But neither the left-hand nor the right-hand derivative exists at $a$,

and that it is 'visually obvious' that the function has these properties (so pathological functions like the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) are excluded). For the purposes of this question, I will define 'visually obvious' as meaning that it is possible to guess that the function has the above properties just by looking at its graph.

---

The function $f(x)=|x|$ is probably the simplest example of how a function can be continuous, and yet not differentiable, at a point:

[image: Graph of |x|]

It is clear just by looking at the graph that $f$ is continuous at $0$, but $f'(0)$ does not exist as $f'_+(0)=1$ and $f'_-(0)=-1$. However, what I find unsatisfying about this example is that $f$ is still fairly well-behaved around $0$—it is meaningful to ask about the 'rate of change' of the function, it's just that we get different answers when we zone in from the left-hand side compared to the right-hand side. I'm looking for a function where it is not meaningful to talk about the 'rate of change' at all, and yet the function is still continuous at the point in the question.

Comment: What is semi-differentiability? I can't find an exact definition for it

Comment: So are we need to find out a function which is continuous at a point but one sided derivative not exist at the same point . Is it the summary of whole problem ?

Comment: The question is not clear to me what about $xsin(1/x)$ suitabley defined at $0$ ?

Comment: Something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)?

Comment: @Buraian: A function is semi-differentiable at a point if the left-hand derivative exists or the right-hand derivative exists. So $|x|$ is semi-differentiable at $0$, for example; $x^2$ is also semi-differentiable at $0$ (because it is differentiable at $0$). However, the function$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x\sin(1/x) &\text{if $x\neq0$} \\
0 &\text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$ is not semi-differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @AmitMittal: Yep, neither of the one-sided derivatives are allowed to exist. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @PaxDaga: What exactly isn't clear to you? I am happy to explain. Anyway, $x\sin(1/x)$ is a good example—you can post that as answer, if you wish.

Comment: @Klaus: That's an interesting example. Perhaps it is not 'visually obvious', but this is a subjective term anyway.

Comment: I don’t see why you are looking at functions that are continuous on a neighbourhood for your examples. Any function that is only continuous at a and not anywhere else provides a fine example like say the...what’s it called, thomae function? Popcorn? Don’t remember...

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Not *continuous* in a neighbourhood of $a$, but defined in a neighbourhood of $a$. The reason I specified this is that functions such as $f(n)=n$ for integer $n$ are trivially continuous at each point, but not differentiable. However, we couldn't even conceivably find the derivative of $f$, as the concept of "differentiability at the point $a$" only applies to functions which are defined in a neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: @Buraian: Apparently the term semi-differentiable has been raised to "semi-standard terminology" [by Wikipedia writers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability) who don't have much of a background in these matters (evidenced to me by the inappropriate and scant reference list there). Note, for example, the term is used [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1976-82-05/S0002-9904-1976-14157-2/S0002-9904-1976-14157-2.pdf) (middle p. 770) for a semicontinuity analog of differentiability. The many decades-old standard terms are "unilateral derivative" and "one-sided derivative".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I've edited my post to use more standard terminology.

Comment: For what it's worth, my comment wasn't intended as a criticism your usage, as I assume the term "semi-derivative" is being spread by the Wikipedia page, which has only three references --- one a lesser known calculus text, one a research paper having virtually no reference significance for the topic at hand, and Dirac's quantum mechanics book (?!?). While I'm here, you might find Klymchuk's [**Counterexamples in Calculus**](https://stemtec.aut.ac.nz/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/57639/Counterexamples-in-Calculus-MAA-e-book.pdf) useful.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: That's a very nice suggestion. Thank you. Instructional counterexamples are of immense value to me: I recently learnt about [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function), which is differentiable everywhere, but the derivative is bounded everywhere, and nowhere Riemann integrable. These examples always help me refine my intuition.

Comment: In a certain sense, almost all functions with a bounded derivative are not Riemann integrable on any non-singleton interval, and even worse than this. Not being Riemann integrable on an interval is equivalent to the derivative being discontinuous on a set of positive measure, which allows for "sortta nice" functions that are also continuous on a set of positive measure (which Volterra functions are). However, "most" functions having a bounded derivative are such that [the derivative is continuous only a set of measure zero (and worse still)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/13130).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the function $x\sin(1/x)$, continuously extended at $0$. The left and right derivatives at $0$ don't exist as $\sin(1/h)$ keeps oscillating between $-1$ and $1$ as $h\to 0$:

[image: Graph of xsin(1/x)]

Comment: @Joe Thank you for your edit.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t seem to have understood my comment so let me try an answer. The weierstrass function, $|x|^s$, $x\sin1/x$, these functions are all continuous **on a neighbourhood of 0**. But your question is asking for functions continuous only **at one point**.  So you can consider the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x &x\in \mathbb Q\\ -x &x\not\in \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$
Note that the function is everywhere defined on $\mathbb R$. Its graph is X shaped, consisting of the two lines $y=\pm x$ (what you can’t ‘draw’ is that there are infinitely many holes in any interval.) Clearly there are two candidates for the (left or right) gradient at $0$; since the (left or right) gradient must be unique, it’s not (left or right) differentiable at $0$. But it is continuous at $0$. It’s not continuous anywhere else (and therefore, not differentiable anywhere else.)

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another fairly standard example is $f(x) = x^{2/3}$, which (like the absolute value function) has a cusp at $x = 0$, but which (unlike the absolute value function) has neither a left-handed nor a right-handed derivative, because the graph of $y=f'(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x = 0$.
[image]

Comment: My favourite version of this is $|x|^{s-1}x$ whose graph is a differentiable curve but the graph coordinates break down in the manner you described