# Does differentiating a differentiable function give a differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to know that if a differentiable function is differentiated, it is still differentiable.

I mean, let $f \ $ be a differentiable function, and $f' \ $ its derivative.
Is $f' \ $ always also a differentiable function?

Comment: Not necessarily. $f'$ does not even need to be continuous, let alone differentiability.

Comment: Is there some reason you think it would be? Your insight and investigation could be very valuable!

Comment: Take a function that isn't differentiable. Integrate it. You now have a function that is differentiable, with nondifferentiable derivative. Simples!

Comment: See this great answer by Dave Renfro to the question [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/169852) Spoiler alert: *very* discontinuous, for numerous definitions of "very". Btw, it's worth mentioning that for functions of a complex variable, differentiable (on, say, an open set) *does* imply that the derivative is differentiable, hence complex differentiable functions are infinitely differentiable, and even better, they are analytic (can be expressed at least locally as a power series).

Comment: Mathematicians care a good amount about how differentiable a function is, so much that there is a definition: a function $f$ is of class $C^r$ if it is $r$th order continuously differentiable; i.e., if its $r$th derivative exists and is continuous. We call $C^\infty$ functions *smooth*.