# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx) f(x) \, dx = 0$ and its Fourier intuition

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, fourier-analysis

Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx) f(x) \, dx = 0$, with $f: [-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable.

*Note: There are proofs of stronger statements on this site and elsewhere.  My goal is to verify* my (simple) *proof, and to get answers to the two questions in* discussion *below.*

**Proof:**
Let $v(x) = \frac{-\cos nx}{n}, v'(x) = \sin nx$.  Through integration by parts, we have $$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx) f(x) \, dx =  f(\pi)v(\pi) - f(-\pi)v(-\pi) + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos nx}{n} f'(x) \, dx.
$$

Since $f(\pi), f(-\pi), f'(\pi), f'(-\pi)$ are each constant, and $\cos$ is bounded, all the terms go to zero as $n \to \infty$.

**Discussion:**

1. The [original question](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_hw_final.pdf) specified $f$ as *continuously* differentiable.  However, unless I'm in error, that is not required.
2. Intuitively, this reminds of Fourier analysis (which I've yet to study), and says *If you beat any nice periodic function with a high enough frequency wave, you'll get a constant zero*.  Alternatively: *As frequency rises, the corresponding component of a nice periodic function will eventually go to zero*.  Is my intuition correct? Can you clarify?

Comment: For $2)$, yes. The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is saying that the amplitudes of the $n$th frequency tone vanishes as $n\to\infty$

Comment: For 1): the [Riemann–Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) even holds if this $f$ is only integrable on $[-\pi,\pi].$ But for your integration by parts, I don't think $f$ differentiable is sufficient: what would your last integral mean? For 2): another interpretation is: the Fourier coefficients of a periodic (integrable) function form a null sequence.

Comment: @AnneBauval My understanding is that any derivative of a function has at most countable discontinuities, and that we can take the integral of any function with countable discontinuities.

Comment: @AnneBauval Why can't we take integral of function with countable discontinuities?

Comment: We can, but $\cos(nx)f'(x)$ is not such a function. It can be *very* discontinuous: see [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be). I wonder to which function you are thinking when talking about "countable discontinuities", since $f$ has none.

Comment: The proof holds only under the assumption that $f'$ is integrable (so not too unbounded if you want) and that is generally not true as $f'$ can be non integrable (see $x^2\sin 1/x^2$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$) the usual approximation proof is needed

Comment: A derivative is not necessarily integrable (Riemann sense). For example it may be unbounded. But there are bounded derivatives too which are not integrable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function